# I have 2 subsciptions on 2 different observables. If they are both "firing" at the same time i just want to execute 1 of them

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

I have 2 observable with a subscription on each of them. my problem is, if they fire at the same time, the code is influencing each other, so just the functionality of subscription 1 should be fired and sub 2 should be ignored.

```
this.windowRef.window.instance.resizeEnd
            .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef))
            .subscribe(() => {
                //...some code
            });

        this.windowRef.window.instance.stateChange
            .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef))
            .subscribe((state) => {
               //... some code
            });
```

i tried it to solf with rxjs zip, but came here to the problem i have to wait for all subscribe to fire until it triggers, so it won't work there for me

Comment: Nothing happens "at the same time".  You need to define a time window.

Comment: You're probably look for the `race` operator

Comment: Problem with the race operator is, that it just uses the first value, but they both can emit values multiple times and if there are like 500ms between emitting values, i want to react to all of them

Comment: check this , it might solve your problem , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63722730/rxjs-emit-a-value-only-if-the-first-source-observable-emits-a-value-and-not-ot